# Beaker Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby, puppet, beaker-testing

I am writing an acceptance test for my Puppet module using Beaker. My module depends on PuppetDB to get some info. To add PuppetDB dependency, I added `dependency 'puppetlabs/puppetdb'` to my Modulefile and this

```
mod 'puppetlabs/puppetdb',
   path: 'puppet',
   git: 'https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb.git'
```

to my Puppetfile. However, when I run my acceptance test, I get `Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

I googled and tried multiple approaches like giving the correct permission to /etc/hosts file, manually running PuppetDB on the VM created by Beaker, but I can't go past this error. It would be great if anyone put me in right direction. Considering I am new to Puppet and Beaker, is it even possible to write an acceptance test for the module that depends on PuppetDB?